# Spring JPA: findAll() as HashMap?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

```
    Iterable<Company> _companies = companyRepository.findAll();
    Map<Long, Company> companies = new HashMap();
    _companies.forEach((Company c) -> {
        companies.put(c.getId(), c);
    });
```

Comment: Why are you wanting to do this in the first place? Note that you generally shouldn't be saving JPA entities outside of the transaction they're a part of, so you if this is some sort of reference data it's best to keep a detached copy. If it's not, then you should just look it back up on each request.

Comment: I need to iterate over all entities, and inside iteration, still need to access them by ID. (calling repository.findById each time would be ouchy).

Comment: You need to iterate over them for what purpose? (Among other things, note that Spring Data supports `Stream<Company>` as a return type.)